# Get list of pull request refs that have been merged into master

Tags: git, github

I need to retrieve a list of PR **numbers** that have been merged into `master`. Is this possible with the `git` command line? I cannot seem to be able to find an example of this.

Comment: git doesn't have any notion or PR. So no.

Comment: if your PR comments have some consistent format, your should be able to parse your git log for them.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git ls-remote <repo_url> refs/pull/*/merge | awk '{split($2,a,"/");print a[3]}'
```

A pull request of Github is a ref like `refs/pull/*/head`. If it's accepted, a ref `refs/pull/*/merge` is created. `*` is the PR number.

`git ls-remote` retrieves the refs in the format `refs/pull/*/merge` with their commits in the front.

`awk` splits `refs/pull/*/merge` with `/` as the delimiter and prints the 3rd part, the PR number.

But it works only if all the PRs are merged to `master`. I'm not sure if PRs could be accepted to other branches. If they could be, you need to fetch these refs and `master` to the local repository and find those reachable from `master`.

```
git init foo
git fetch <repo_url> refs/pull/*/merge:refs/pull/*/merge
git fetch <repo_url> refs/heads/master
git for-each-ref refs/pull/*/merge  --format="%(refname)" --merged=FETCH_HEAD
```

But note that it does not work for the PRs which are squash-merged.

Comment: I don't think this works for a gitlab though. Perhaps in the gitlab we need to do something like this `refs/*` or `refs/merge-requests/*/head`